# compare aggregate value across groups

Tags: r, dplyr

With a df below,

1. need to compute median for variable `metric` across the teams tm1, tm2 and tm3 on a per `locid`, `day`, `hour` combo basis
2. then filter only those `locid`, `day`, `hour` observations which have the same `metric` median across teams `tm1`, `tm2`, `tm3`.

   ```
   set.seed(100)
   df <- data.frame(
       locid = sample(c(1111,1122,1133), 20, replace=TRUE),
       day = sample(c(1:3), 20, replace=TRUE),
       hour = sample(c(1:4), 20, replace=TRUE),
       team = sample(c("tm1", "tm2", "tm3"), 20, replace=TRUE),
       metric = sample(1:5, 20, replace=TRUE )
   )
   ```

my attempt

```
df_medians <- df %>% 
                group_by(locid + day + hour + team) %>%
                  summarise(metric_median = median(metric))
```

this gives the `median` per `team` for each `locid + day + hour`. I need to now find out the `locid + day + hour` combos that give the same median value across teams `tm1`, `tm2`, `tm3`.

`df_medians %>% group_by(locid, day, hour, team) %>% summarise(??what here??)`

I was trying with dplyr, but base-r solution is fine.

As a simpler example we can look at the below data-  which has measurements from two different locations for two teams.

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+
| locid |  day |  hour |  team |  metric |
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       3 |
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       2 |
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       1 |

|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       1 |
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       2 |
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       3 |

|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       3 |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       2 |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       1 |

|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       1 |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       2 |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       1 |
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+
```

step 1 - compute median by group

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------------+
| locid |  day |  hour |  team |  metric_med |
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       2     |
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       2     |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm1  |       2     |
|  1122 |    1 |     1 |  tm2  |       1     |
+-------+------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Step2 - compare medians across group (locid + day + hour) only (1111, 1, 1) has the metric_med same across the teams gp1 and gp2

```
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
| locid |  day |  hour |  metric_med |
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1111 |    1 |     1 |       2     |
+-------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: can you add expected result?

Comment: You can spread your team columns and then mutate rowwise

Comment: Cannot understand what you want. Same median value for 3 teams in all groups?

Comment: @Feng yes, rows with same median value for 3 teams in all groups.

Comment: @yeedle  - added a simpler example with output

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to spread the groups into one row per each locid, day, and hour, and then compare them. This solution scales well for more than two groups and complicated conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(locid, day, hour, team) %>% 
  summarize(median = median(metric)) %>%
  spread(team, median) %>% 
  filter(tm1 == tm2)
```

Another possible solution is to arrange the summarized results by locid, day, and hour, and then compare the median in one row to its `lag`. This solution only works for two groups in team.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(locid, day, hour, team) %>% 
  summarize(median = median(metric)) %>%
  arrange(locid, day, hour) %>% 
  filter(median == lag(median))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's re-cast 'all equal' to mean "zero-variance or a single observation".  Thus:

`df %>%
  # per locid, day, hour, team
  group_by(locid, day, hour, team) %>%
  # compute median
  summarize(team_median = median(metric)) %>%
  # ungroup before specifying new grouping
  ungroup %>%
  # for locid, day, hour
  group_by(locid, day, hour) %>%
  # find the medians that were the same for all teams
  # 'the same' here is taken to mean no variance
  # or having a single observation
  # note that, although logical vector TRUE | NA does yield TRUE
  # this is only because it must yield TRUE.
  # As another example, FALSE | NA, yields NA.
  # As a guard against team_medians that are NA, I add a coalesce wrapper.
  # I've decided that missing team_medians represent non-cases, YMMV
  summarize(all_equal = coalesce(n() == 1 | var(team_median) == 0), FALSE) %>%
  filter(all_equal == TRUE) %>%
  select(-all_equal)`